# What is recommended use case of @Access(AccessType.FIELD)

Tags: java, hibernate

As far as I know if I use Field access type @Access(AccessType.FIELD) then Hibernate will access the FIELD directly and not use the getter or setter.

But, I am not sure regarding the use case of this. In which scenario it is recommended to access the field directly instead of getter or setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Hibernate/JPA supports both accessor method and field based access type as you already aware of.

In most of the situations in **rich domain model**, setter method may need to have some validation

**Accessor method**

```
Public void setPrice(final  float price)
{
// perform some business validation plus few more operation as per the requirement 
this.price = price;
}
```

The above case will **take bit more time** for ORM engine to populate an entity. But in field based access will take **comparatively less time** to populate an entity.

Hope This is helpful